# Dynamic Programming Problem (Input Inconsistencies?)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve the [word break](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/) problem in LeetCode, and I can't understand why the following inputs are not evaluated in the same way - from my perspective, it doesn't make sense one to be true and the other false. Can someone explain it to me?

Why this input is false ?

```
"catsandog" ["cats","dog","sand","and","cat"]
```

and this one is true

```
"cars" ["car","ca","rs"]
```

Comment: `Word break` means non-overlapping words found in the dictionary constituting the entire  final word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "cars" can be broken into "ca" and "rs" which exists in given dictionary  ["car","ca","rs"].

On the other hand, "catsandog" can not be broken into words such that all the words exists in  ["cats","dog","sand","and","cat"].

For example,
we can break "catsandog" in the following way:

> "catsandog" ="cat"+"sand"+"og",
>    "catsandog"= "cats"+"and"+"og",

but "og" does not exits in the given dictionary ["cats","dog","sand","and","cat"].

So in this problem, if you can break the given word into some words such that all of them exists in a given dictionary , then you will return true.

But if at least one word of your broken words does not exist in the given dictionary, then you will return false.